# Prove that these integrals are equal. How to complete the proof?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^xf(u)(x-u)^2du=2\int_0^x\left(\int_0^{u_2}\left(\int_0^{u_1}f(t)dt\right)du_1\right)du_2$$

Ok, I derived both parts 2 times wrt $x$ and got equal integrals. But I'm suspicious whether it is enough or not. Since two integrals can be differ by constant, so equality of their derivatives implies equality of integrals. But since we derived two times, we have that equality of derivatives implies that initial expressions can be differed by $ax+b$. So how to show strictly that these integrals actually allow to add or to subtract the expressions of form $ax+b$?

Comment: $du$ or $du_2$?

Comment: If you have $F''(x)=G''(x)$ everywhere, what you need to show that $F=G$ is just that, for example $F(0)=G(0)$ and $F'(0)=G'(0)$.

Comment: thanks, there is $du_2$ instead of $du$ on the right hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that these integrals exist you could proceed as follows:

\begin{align}
2\int_0^x\int_0^{u}\int_0^{u_1}f(t)dtdu_1du&=2\int_0^x\int_0^{u}\int_t^{u}f(t)du_1dtdu\\
&=2\int_0^x\int_0^{u}(u-t)f(t)dtdu\\
&=2\int_0^x\int_t^{x}(u-t)f(t)dudt\\
&=\int_0^x(t-u)^2f(t)dt\\
\end{align}

Comment: I don't know why we can change places of differentials so easily. I mean that I'm new in integrals, so I wait until my textbook asks for proving this kind of tricks. Otherwise I'm not going to accept this fact as belief. Anyway my question has been answered by @HenningMakholm. Thanks for try.

Comment: If integrals exist then you could you Fubini: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many details, so I don't think that you can assume that $f$ is at least continuous. If it's not then LHS of the equality may not be differentiable.

Here all you need to do is integrate by parts twice.